# ASP.NET MVC Create a new Guid by buttonclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, guid

Im trying to generate a new GUID every time im clicking a button wiuthoput reloading the whole view and i cant figure out what to do.
This is the function

```
Guid.NewGuid()
```

by clicking a button in my Razorview. I tried it in javascript

```
 $("#buttonclick").click(function () {
    function createNewGuid() {
        return new Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    var guid = createNewGuid();
    console.log(guid);
}
```

and this method is just given the same guid every time i click the button.
I also tried it in MVC Razor with

```
return "@Guid.NewGuid()"
```

and still gets the same result.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/105074/4868839)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do Generate guid in javascript. like the below code by the use of Regular expressions

```js
$("#buttonclick").click(function () {
    var guid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {  
      var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c === 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);  
      return v.toString(16);  
   }); 
  console.log(guid);
  alert(guid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonclick">Generate Guid</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use?:

```
function createNewGuid() {
   return guid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
$("#buttonclick").click(function() {
  function createNewGuid() {
    function s4() {
      return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
        .toString(16)
        .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
      s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
  }
  var guid = createNewGuid();
  console.log(guid);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonclick">guid</button>
```

Comment: ok this is the solution ive been looking for thanks. but im still thinking why Guid.NewGuid() wont work should do the same

Comment: @ChrisG well i dont see the point in helping you figure out why the Guid.NewGuid() dont work if you change mark answers often

Comment: Hahaha sry i thoutgh i can mark more than one answer as right